# WebOb 0.9 is on sys.path before WebOb 1.1.1

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm building a GAE python 2.7 app.  During debugging, I noticed that the Request class used by webapp2 is based on the one from webob 0.9, which is not the version I specified in app.yaml:

```
libraries:
- name: webob
  version: "1.1.1"
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
```

It appears the problem is that dev_appserver.py modifies sys.path, adding various third-party libraries before it reads app.yaml, and thus doesn't know which version, if any, to add to sys.path.  For example:

```
EXTRA_PATHS = [
  DIR_PATH,
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'antlr3'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'django_0_96'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'fancy_urllib'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'ipaddr'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'jinja2'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'protorpc'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'PyAMF'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'markupsafe'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'webob_0_9'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'webapp2'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'yaml', 'lib'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'simplejson'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'google.appengine._internal.graphy'),
]
```

I'm looking for workaround ideas; for now I'll modify my local copy of dev_appserver.py, but that'll get wiped out next time I upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use devappserver2. (devappserver2 is experimental now, but not support Python 2.5)

```
import devappserver2
devappserver2.fix_sys_path()
```

The `devappserver2.fix_sys_path` adding webob-1.2.3, webapp2-2.5.1 and jinja2-2.6 to sys.path.

https://code.google.com/p/appengine-devappserver2-experiment/

OR

2) Google App Engine 1.7.6 Pre-release SDKs Available.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topicsearchin/google-appengine/webob/google-appengine/qyT3mvTd2RU

It's fixed this problem.

> - Fixed an issue with the new dev_appserver to have fix_sys_path add the necessary libraries to sys.path making it now compatible with the testbed.
>     https://code.google.com/p/appengine-devappserver2-experiment/issues/detail?id=45